# Changing storage engine to InnoDb from MyIsam is dropping records from table

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam, phpmyadmin

Currently our Database all tables are using MyIsam as a storage engine. We tried changing storage engine of our mysql tables from MyISAM to InnoDB from PHPMyAdmin operations tab. However during the change table records are dropped. So what can be the possible factor causing this problem.

This is what we tried:

We converted test_user table which was having storage engine MyIsam and was having total records 11k. When we converted it into InnoDB the records droped to 9k. This happened for many tables. Not sure what we are doing wrong.

Comment: instead of converting copy the data to a new table, and see what innodb doesn't like.

Comment: @nbk let me try it this way as well

Answer (score 0):

Are you are using `SHOW TABLE STATUS` to determine that there is a loss?  Don't trust it.  The "Rows" is an estimate in the case of InnoDB.  Use `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl` to get the exact row count.

More tips on the conversion:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb

Comment: Yes I know that it shows an approximate incase of `InnoDB` but `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl` also returned the same records as the phpmyadmin showed.

Comment: @SohaIbAhmEd - OK.  Can you tell if the missing rows are the first few rows, or the last few, or some other pattern?

Comment: Sorry but couldn't tell exactly from where the rows got missing.